# Prove that if $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, then $T(v_1),T(v_2),\dots,T(v_n)$ is also.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove that if $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, then  $T(v_1),T(v_2),\dots,T(v_n)$ is also. where $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$

We know that since $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, then:

$$r_1\vec{v_1}+r_2\vec{v_2}+\dots+r_n\vec{v_n}=\vec{0}$$

$$T(r_1\vec{v_1}+r_2\vec{v_2}+\dots+r_n\vec{v_n})=T(\vec{0})$$

$$T(r_1\vec{v_1}+r_2\vec{v_2}+\dots+r_n\vec{v_n})=\vec{0}\in\mathbb{R}^m$$

$$\therefore r_1\vec{v_1}+r_2\vec{v_2}+\dots+r_n\vec{v_n}\in\ker(T)$$

but this is as far as I got. What to do next?

Comment: This is not true in general without more conditions on $T$. Did you mean the reverse implication?

Comment: I think the reverse is not always true, but I think this one is?

Comment: This is clearly false in general -- consider $T=0$.

Comment: The reverse is true in general, yes.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri by $0$ you just mean $T$ sets anything it gets to the $0$ vector?

Comment: @KSplitX Precisely. The reverse, in the following sense, is true: let $T:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation. If $\{Tv_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is linearly independent, then $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is also linearly independet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect here you're requiring $T$ to be a full rank linear transformation and you also require $n\leq m$. If $n\geq m$ then $T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)$ is a set of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and cannot be linearly independent (there are too many). If it's not a full rank linear transformation you can come up with counter examples for $T$ that only map to subspaces of $R^n$ and come up with a similar problem (T=0 is a useful examples).

Hint: With this being the case, try going for a proof by contradiction, suppose $T(v_1),T(v_2),\dots,T(v_n)$ was not linearly independent, what can you say about $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$? You'll definitely want to use linearity in there somewhere.